# Error creating bean with name 'triangle' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor

Tags: java, spring

hi i am new to springs and i am trying a basic program in springs.here is my code template

**SpringDemo.java**

```
    public class SpringDemo {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
                Triangle triangle=(Triangle)context.getBean("triangle");
                triangle.draw();
            }
    }
```

**Triangle.java**

```
    package org.amulya.springs;

    public class Triangle {
        private Point pointA;
        private Point pointB;
        private Point pointC;

        public Point getPointA() {
            return pointA;
        }

        public void setPointA(Point pointA) {
            this.pointA = pointA;
        }

        public Point getPointB() {
            return pointB;
        }

        public void setPointB(Point pointB) {
            this.pointB = pointB;
        }

        public Point getPointC() {
            return pointC;
        }

        public void setPointC(Point pointC) {
            this.pointC = pointC;
        }

        public void draw() {
            System.out.println("pointA is (" + getPointA().getX() + "," + getPointA().getY() + ")");
            System.out.println("pointB is (" + getPointB().getX() + "," + getPointB().getY() + ")");
            System.out.println("pointC is (" + getPointC().getX() + "," + getPointC().getY() + ")");
        }
    }
```

**spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">


<beans>
    <bean id="triangle" class="org.amulya.springs.Triangle">
    <property name="pointA" ref="zeropoint"/>
    <property name="pointB" ref="point1"/>
    <property name="pointC" ref="point2"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="zeropoint" class="org.amulya.springs.Point">
    <property name="x" value="0"/>
    <property name="x" value="0"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="point1" class="org.amulya.springs.Point">
    <property name="x" value="-20"/>
    <property name="x" value="0"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="point2" class="org.amulya.springs.Point">
    <property name="x" value="20"/>
    <property name="x" value="0"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**point.java**

```
    package org.amulya.springs;

    public class Point {
        private int x;
        private int y;
        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }
        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }
        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }
        public void setY(int y) {
            this.y = y;
        }

    }
```

> spring.xml : /SpringDemo/src/spring.xml

**Exception:**

> Error creating bean with name 'triangle' defined in class path
>   resource [spring.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint:
>   specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type
>   ambiguities)

please help me

Comment: Doesn't solve your problem, but in your XML, you're setting `x` twice on each Point, and not setting `y`.

Comment: Your code works fine for me, once I change the second `x` to a `y` in each of the XML Point definitions. Are you sure you've included all your code? Maybe you've not shown us a constructor in `Triangle`? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean id="zeropoint" class="org.amulya.springs.Point">
    <property name="x" value="0"/>
    <property name="x" value="0"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="point1" class="org.amulya.springs.Point">
    <property name="x" value="-20"/>
    <property name="x" value="0"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="point2" class="org.amulya.springs.Point">
    <property name="x" value="20"/>
    <property name="x" value="0"/>
    </bean>
```

in this code change the property name to **X and Y**

the error comes  due to ambiguity

Comment: This doesn't explain the OP's error. The error due to this is completely different: `Configuration problem: Multiple 'property' definitions for property 'x'`